# Problems with Vscode port forwarding to localhost when using a tunnel to VPS

Tags: visual-studio-code, portforwarding

Steps to reproduce:

1. create a ssh connection to vps using any user (`root or non root`)
2. turn ssh connection into a tunnel with `code tunnel`
3. now forward a port, vscode creates a url it doesn't work

What happens is you get a `https://51f222222-8080.euw.devtunnels.ms/` link which is for port `8080`.

So:
`https://<random>-<port>.<area>.devtunnels.ms/`

Is it possible to get a `http://localhost:8080/` forward?

So [VPS] ---(tunnel)--- [localmachine] doesn't work.
So [VPS] ---(SSH)--- [localmachine] does work.

I tried `connecting over SSH` only to my VPS, that worked.
I tried `developing` on my local machine (Macbook Pro M2), that worked.
I tried `DevContainer` both on local machine as VPS via SSH, both worked.

Also, Connecting to VPN, while using Tunnel, also doesn't work.

This is Curl when it does work:
curl -vk https://localhost:7080/

- Trying 127.0.0.1:7080...
- Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7080 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
  ...

This is Curl when it doesn't (I close all Vscode Windows with SSH connection)
curl -vk https://localhost:7080/

- Trying [::1]:7080...
- connect to ::1 port 7080 failed: Connection refused
- Trying 127.0.0.1:7080...
- connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7080 failed: Connection refused
- Failed to connect to localhost port 7080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
- Closing connection
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7080 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server